# Automatically insert createdAt and updatedAt properties for a model in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, loopbackjs

I have a persisted model in my **loopback** app and I want to automatically add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` attributes for this model instances accordingly. What is the easy way to achieve this?

Comment: It's better to add some part of your code for better understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In loopback 3 I have figured a great way to insert `createdAt` and `updatedAt` for a model using a mixin. The mixin name is `loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin` and you can install its module using the command

```
 npm i loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin --save
```

Then you can add the mixin in the `mixins` property found in `server/model-config.json` as the following

```
"mixins": [
  "loopback/common/mixins",
  "../node_modules/loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin",
  "../common/mixins"
]
```

Finally, you can insert createdAt and updatedAt for a model by specifying

```
"Timestamp": true
```

in the `mixins` property of the model json file.

You can also get more details about this mixin [here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin)